# R nested for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to do a nested for loop in R and am a bit confused on how to make it work. I want to assign rows 1:4 of matrix m based upon a function of i. Below I have generalization of my current code. I believe I need to double loop as my actual code for i depends on the values 5, 10, 15, 25.

```r
f <- function()
m <- matrix(nrow = 4)
for (i in c(5, 10, 15, 25)) {
for (j in c(1:4)) {
    m[j,1] <- f(i)
}
}
```

which results in:

```r
> m
     [,1]
[1,]  f(25)
[2,]  f(25)
[3,]  f(25)
[4,]  f(25)
```

My desired output is below and I'm not sure how to do the loop to produce these results.

```r
> m
     [,1]
[1,]  f(5)
[2,]  f(10)
[3,]  f(15)
[4,]  f(25)
```

Comment: You outer loop starts, fills rows 1 to 4 with 5's, then the second iteration fills all rows with 10's etc till in the last iteration all rows are filled with 25. If you do not insists on a double `for`-loop, try `m <- matrix(nrow = 4); x <- c(5, 10, 15, 25); for (i in seq_along(x)) {m[i,1] <- x[i]}; m`

Comment: .. or simply `m[,1] <- c(5, 10, 15, 25)`

Comment: I update my question to be more clear. I'm not simply trying to make a  4x1 matrix with the values  5, 10, 15, 25.

Comment: Try `sapply(c(5, 10, 15, 25), f)`

Comment: Okay thanks for your help! Doing the sapply ended up getting the results I wanted. I think it would be hard to do it with loop due to the iteration issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think doing a nested for-loop would be hard so I ended up doing:

```r
f <- function()
sapply(c(5, 10, 15, 25), f) %>%
  matrix()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).